# Відповідник до слова "донат"

Tags: вибір-слова, іншомовні-слова, відповідник

**Донат** - круглий, звичайно солодкий, пиріжок, смажений в олії чи маслі, з діркою посередині. Може бути із різноманітною начинкою та, зазвичай, покритий глазур'ю, медом чи цукровою пудрою.

На [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/donat) основним відповідником пропонують слово "пончик", однак згідно до [Етимологічного словника](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_2003/EtSlUkrM_2003.pdf) - це полонізм, тому ми не можемо його використати. Також там є варіант "пундик", однак згідно до [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8) - це трохи інша страва, а також у нього немає характерної дирочки:

> Пундики — борошняна страва, що вважалася ласощами.
>
> Готувалася вона дуже просто. Робили прісне на яйцях і кисляку або
>   сироватці тісто, як на коржі. Коли тісто відстоювалось, його ще раз
>   добре вимішували, різали на шматки і розкачували качалкою на дуже
>   тоненькі коржі діаметром 20—25 см. Їх підсмажували з обох боків на
>   сковороді у великій кількості жиру (олії, смальцю чи вершкового масла)
>   і складали у полумисок стовпчиком один на один, перекладаючи
>   підсоленою засмажкою з цибулі. Їли пироги гарячими.

Непоганим варіантом здається "дірпух" (дірка+пампух), однак не впенений, що це слово не перечитиме українському словотвору.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Словопедія](http://lang.slovopedia.org.ua/11/53407/174710.html) також пропонує варіант "*пухтик*". Використання цього слова не знайшов. ЕСУМ також не має цього слова, можу лише припустити, що походить від слова пухкий.

А взагалі-то шукати відповідники до національних страв інших кухонь, а саме з [нідерландської](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/doughnut-vs-donut_us_574ef9fbe4b02912b241574c) та [польської](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=UtA6-pyGJmMC&pg=PA670&lpg=PA670&dq=p%C4%85czki+traditional+rose&source=bl&ots=7DEVaVZIb5&sig=cavM8O1Tc1g2Y2DxElU3hb4eaH0&hl=en&ei=IgYLS_aRJ4_K_ga34L3QBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) — невдячна справа. Це усе одно, що шукати відповідник в англійській до слова "борщ" чи "вареники".

Answer (score 0):

Наразі на [словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/donat) "пундик" має найбільшу кількість голосів (мені також цей варіант дуже подобається). Взагалі натрапив на цю сторінку шукаючи в контексті грошей. [Донат](https://tseivo.com/b/LocalWeirdo/t/kgdeea7gmr) - це слово, яке надовго з нами залишиться в контексті грошей. Почитав [відповідники](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/donat-hroshi) й не думаю що щось буде використовуватись.